# How to use currency format with diffrent number format in angular js

Tags: angularjs, currency-formatting, currency-pipe

I want to convert currency as per the regions like US , UK ,India ,Indonesia etc. and also want to convert in the number format as per region.

Example like in US `$ 102,021.21` is written like this but in Indonesian format it will written something like this `RP 102.021,21`

So here both the number format is different. I use to convert currency using currency pipe but when I use number format with pipe one of them is not working.

```
this.results.records[i].totalAmount = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(this.results.records[i].totalAmount);
```

I used this to convert total amount to it's region's number format and currency pipe for convert amount as per currency value. But both are not working at same time. If I put them one by one then it will work. I want to do it at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using angular 1.x or angular 2 and above?

Comment: I am using angular 1.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the following site

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

you can pass locale and currency code to NumberFormat. So this should give you the result you want.

```
  $scope.value=new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-fr', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format($scope.value);
```

Comment: Yeahhh , I used this but it didn't work alongside currency pipe otherwise your answer is right.

Comment: I guess you don't need to use the currency pipe anymore after this, right?

Comment: Yeahhh , I think so.